# How do you bold highlighted text in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to bold and underline on button click, but only apply to the text that is highlighted in a textarea. I've seen some people use `window.getSelection()` and I plugged it in but it wasn't working. I'll show you what I'm dealing with.

```js
function bold() {
  var selection = window.getSelection()
  selection.style.fontWeight = "bold"
}
```

```html
<textarea id="theType"></textarea>
```

Comment: A textarea element can only contain plain text, no formatting of any kind

Comment: then what can I use?

Comment: Google for "HTML rich text editor". There is no trivial solution.

Comment: You can use `contenteditable`(without `textarea`) and then you'd approach it as you're now. But I agree with@JJJ that WYSIWYG editor is better

Comment: Yeah, `contentEditable` property to a div and then `selection.execCommand('bold')` to make them bold or underline or whatever. Note that it may behave differently on different browsers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate, but it should be clear from the linked question that what you're asking is not possible using `<textarea>`.